# The App Name you entered has already been used

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I am getting this error, I used the same name for other app but I have removed it from sale so it should allow me to enter the app name. It's not doing that for now. How can I take the same name for my second app(first one is already removed from sale).

Comment: You can't. Use the same bundle identifier and upload it as the same app

Comment: for that i can't :( because first app is universal and new is only for iphone and apple will not allow that

Comment: Regardless of whether the app is removed from sale or not, you can't have two apps of the same name in iTunes. If you want to use the same exact name for your new app, try renaming the name for your first app to something else first to "release" the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you use the same bundle ID (so you can use the same name), or you use a (even slightly) different name. Sometimes an ! or splitting/combining words can make the difference

- MyApp vs MyApp!
- MyApp vs My App

If either using the same bundle ID or change the name are not an option, then unless Apple made some changes recently (which they often do, but I'm sure you've checked a thousand times), I'm afraid you're SOL.

Comment: I cannot use the same bundle ID because first app is universal and new is only for iphone and apple will not allow that